# wsadmin.sh reading multiline commands from stdin

Tags: websphere, wsadmin, jacl

Piped `wsadmin` can't run scripts with flow control, because in that mode a newline separates commands.

Simple example from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/cxml_jacl.html?lang=en :

```
set numbers {1 3 5 7 11 13}
foreach num $numbers {
    puts $num
}
```

output:

```
[wasuser@oktest-prod-app-2 ~]$ ${WC_WSADMIN:?} -f test.jacl
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node EmProdDmgrNode using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
1
3
5
7
11
13
[wasuser@oktest-prod-app-2 ~]$ ${WC_WSADMIN:?} <test.jacl
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node EmProdDmgrNode using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7029I: For help, enter: "$Help help"
wsadmin>1 3 5 7 11 13
wsadmin>WASX7015E: Exception running command: "foreach num $numbers {"; exception information:
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:

wsadmin>WASX7015E: Exception running command: "puts $num"; exception information:
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:
can't read "num": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $num"
wsadmin>WASX7015E: Exception running command: "}"; exception information:
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:
invalid command name "}"
    while executing
"}"
```

My script is generated. Beside storing it in a temporary file is there a workaround? I know it's possible to do this:

```
foreach num $numbers { puts $num }
```

but what if there must be more than one command in the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a semicolon:

```
foreach num $numbers { puts $num; puts $num }
```

But you're probably better off writing the script to a temporary file.